# Informix: convert TEXT to BSON

Tags: text, type-conversion, informix, bson

In my Informix database we are using an TEXT field, but we like to update it and start to use BSON.
I know I can uses INSERT clause like that: `INSERT bson_field VALUE('{field:value}'::JSON)`, and this works well, but when I try to do:

`UPDATE table SET bson_field = text_field::JSON`  that doesn't work.

> Error: No cast from text to json.
>  SQLState:  IX000
>  ErrorCode:
>   -9634

Of course, the text in text_field is a correct JSON.

Someone knows a way to convert, with a stored procedure or function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bson functions instead.
GenBSON is a good one.
But study the manual product, because there are several options.

Comment: Sadly, genbson does not work against TEXT types. TEXT types are the hardest to deal with since there is no conversion routines between text and other times (they are treated as large objects in the server and are very distinct due to their potential size).  

The only solution I see is to write a little external program (JDBC or other) to query the text field, allow the client drivers to convert that into a string or char [] (language dependent) then update the bson_field with the converted string characters you get.